# Rider does not seem to recognize Unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, rider

I have used Rider in the past on Unity projects, there was a button to start Unity Play mode from the IDE, and attach the debugger. I am using 2019.2 version of Unity and latest of Rider right now.

I should have some icons like in the documentation here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Unity.html#.

Nothing show up, and the best I get, is Rider proposing to add a custom configuration... Rider is correctly set as the IDE for Unity in Unity preferences. I do not understand what is going on.

[image: IDE bar with missing Unity play button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed Rider again, while checking every delete checkbox (cache and settings and more), did not re-use the config from previous version (see https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360005280960-Cannot-attach-Unity-debugger), and also made sure I have Unity support checked. The button is back.

Answer (score 7):

You should go to 'package manager' of unity and upgrade 'Rider package'. Then you have to go to 'preferences' and should see new option appears in external script editor in external tool option select it and your are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

For me (MacOS) it was due to not having mono installed. I opened up visual studio community once, and it prompted me to install some tools. After that I rebooted unity and rider, and everything worked properly.